# iOS8 - iCloud Drive Key-Value-Store

Tags: ios, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore, icloud-drive

for iOS7 I was storing user information concerning inApp Purchase in the iCloud keyvalueStore so that restoring worked on the current device and all other iOS devices of the user. Before the user was able to buy something I was checking if iCloud documents&data for kvs was active to make sure, restoring works ...

The check looks like this (and worked for iOS7):

```
- (BOOL)isICloudEnabledOnThisDevice
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *ubiquityContainerURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    return (ubiquityContainerURL) ? YES : NO;
}
```

After migration to iOS8 and enabling iCloud Drive on my device - i noticed that this check always fails. I am hoping that the kvs is automatically migrated to iCloud drive if activated once -> so I assume I have just to fix this check if iCloud drive (for >iOS8 only) is active on the device - right?

The problem is - I am not really sure how to check this correctly for iOS8 because the API documentation is not really clear about that imho :-/?!

oO

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it - the provisioning profile needed an update because of the xcode 5 compatibility flag ...

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling -[NSFileManager ubiquityIdentityToken] rather than -[NSFileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:] because it's faster.

See the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFileManager/ubiquityIdentityToken